# I have a class library in which I added UwpDesktop nuget package. Same nuget works fine in Windows form but doesn't work in class library

Tags: c#, uwp, file-access

I have integrated this function in my class library. Everything works fine in function but when it comes to `GetFileFromPathAsync()`, it just seems to not move forward and does not throw any exception, either, although I have added try catch.

My class library function works in such a way that its output path of .dlls is in separate folder. I test this class library with GUI Application that outputs its resources in same folder as in class library. Any help would be appreciated

```
private static async Task<string> WindowsMediaOCR(string ImagePath, LanguageEnum language)
{
    try
    {
        // ... Some code not related to below code
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() +"\\tempImage.bmp")
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
        var ocrResult = await engine.RecognizeAsync(softwareBitmap);
        string readText = ocrResult.Text;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code of `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync` og what lib is `StorageFile`?

Comment: @FrankNielsen Its just c# library. Search it and you will find it easily

Comment: I can't find the source, but if `GetFileFromPathAsync()` blocks/deadlock as you say. I am pretty sure that some `SynchronizationContext` is going on. Can you surround the call or calle with a "Dispatch to main thread" something, depending on the target exe form.

Answer (score 1):

> it just seems to not `move forward and does not throw any exception`, either, although I have added try catch.

The problem is that `WindowsMediaOCR` is async method and it's return type is  `Task<string>`, so you need to place await key word before calling the method. and please correct above method that need a string return type. For more info please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps).

```
var str = await CorLib.WindowsMediaOCR();
```